# Intellij idea doesn't show folder out in project view

Tags: intellij-idea

The folder 'out' isn't shown in project view but it is created on file system.
Does anyone have same problem?

Windows View:

[image: Windows view]

Project View:

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot of your project view.

Comment: How can I add screenshot to question?

Comment: There is a button to add image after you press edit under the question.

Comment: In your project tool-window's upper right corner, there's a _"cog"_ icon, with the tooltip _"Show options menu"_. Click it and verify that the _"Show Excluded Files"_ option is  checked/ticked. Alternatively, pres SHIFT twice, search for _"show excluded files"_, and check that the option is _"ON"_.

Comment: Morfic, thank you very much. It works.

Comment: Cool, I'll post it as an answer to better illustrate this. **P.S.** If you reply to someone's comment please use @username so they get a notification. Also you don't have enough reputation to directly post images, but until you get to that point, someone will edit your question to inline them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IJ has a *"Show Excluded Files"* option which you need to make sure is **enabled/activated**. You can access it in at least 2 ways:

- in your project tool-window's upper right corner there's a *"cog"* icon, with the tooltip *"Show options menu"*. Click it and verify that the *"Show Excluded Files"* option is checked/ticked

  [image: accessing from the project tool window]
- alternatively, pres <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> twice (search everywhere), type *"show excl..."*, and check under the *"Action"* section that the option is *"ON"*

  [image: accessing from search everywhere]